# Nested matching group in regex

Tags: regular-expression, replace

I have a common usecase when I transform some python expression the following way:

```
value 1
value 2
value 3
```

into

```
['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3']
```

The easiest way may be to use a mapping, but I wanted to use a substitution for this task.

So far I got:

```
s/\(.*\n\)\+/[&]/g
```

Which result in

```
[value 1
value 2
value 3
]
```

This raise a question, because I want to be able to match the `\(.*\)`, but not the `\n` and the use the result of the matched inside a `'...'`.

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in a single substitution, but you could do it in 2 while in visual mode (after selecting the python expression): `:'<,'>s/\v(.*)\n/'\1', / | s/\v(.*), /[\1]/` You could transform this into a visual mapping: `xnoremap ,x :s/\v(.*)\n/'\1', / <Bar> s/\v(.*), /[\1]/<CR>` and maybe into a normal mapping if the expression is inside a paragraph: `nnoremap ,x :'{+1,'}-1s/\v(.*)\n/'\1', / <Bar> s/\v(.*), /[\1]/<CR>` Here the mapping would be `,x`.

Comment: couldn't do with regex, but using external commands `:%! echo "[$(sed "s/.*/'&',/" % | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/, $//')]"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

It is possible to do this in one expression if we use a "sub-replace-expression." See bottom for info on that.

**/Edit**

The problem here is that you want to do two different things.

1. Operate on the match as a whole (i.e. surround it with `[]`)
2. Operate on each item in the match (i.e. surround them with `'',`)

You can easily do either one:

1. `:s/\(.\+\n\)\+/[&]/`
2. `:%s/\(.\+\)\n/'\1', /`

but as far as I know there's no way to do both in a single operation. I did try to get the proper output with something like:

```
:s/\(\(.\+\)\n\)\+/[\2]/
```

But of course the problem with this is that the `\2` matches only the last match from the second set of memory parentheses `\(\)` and doesn't "remember" anything before that. So you end up with only the last line.

I would recommend doing some pre/post processing with an additional `:s///` command to get rid of the newlines before/after the fact. Here's what I came up with

```
function! FormatExpression()
   .,/\n^$/s/\(.*\)\n/'\1', /
   s/\(.*\), /[\1]/
endfunction
```

1st line (Remove newlines)

- `.,/\n^$/` This is a range modifier for the search and replace. Without this, the command will go on to mutilate your entire file. Currently it goes from the current line `.`, to the next blank line `\n^$`. I'm not sure how you were intending to split things up, but you need some way to tell it to stop.
- `s/` The beginning of a search and replace command
- `\(.*\)\n` Match the whole line, but only save the part without the newline.
- `'\1',` Replace line with the match surrounded by single quotes and append a comma.

2nd line (Surround in brackets)

- `\(.*\),` Match the whole line but not the last comma and space
- `[\1]` Surround with brackets and also remove superfluous ending comma and space.

I'm going to keep looking into this, but at the moment I don't think it's possible with a single expression. :(

**EDIT:**

I have found a way to do this with one expression! Internally this is actually two substitutions, but it *is* technically one expression. Here's what I came up with:

```
:s/\v((.+\n)*.+)\n/\= "['" . substitute(submatch(1), '\n', "', '", 'g') . "']" /
```

- `:s///`: Do a substitution
- `\v((.+\n)*.+)\n`: Basically gathers up all the next non-blank lines and stores it all except for the final `\n`
- `\=` Allows us to use an expression in the replacement (see `:h sub-replace-expression`)
- `substitute(submatch(1)...)`: Replaces all stored `\n` with `', '`
- `"['" . ... . "']"`: Prepends `['` and appends `']`

This will start at the position of the cursor and go until it finds a blank line (`^\n`). Not grabbing the last `\n` is important as without that bit we're left with an additional `',` that we don't want at the end.

Some might consider this more complex than the previous two-expression answer. But I thought I would go ahead and add this since it is in fact possible to do it with one expression. :)

Answer (score 2):

Visually highlight, then:

```
:'<,'> s/.*/['&']/ | *j! | s/]\[/, /ge
```

It surrounds each line, to make e.g. `['value 1']`, joins
them all, then replaces adjacent `]` and `[` with comma-space.

The documentation for the `*` in `*j!` is at `:help cpo-star`, by the way. 
That one's a bit tricky to find.

Comment: Nice work around :)

Comment: Actually you can use `:'<,'>s/\v(.*)(\_.)/['\1']/` and remove the joining.

Comment: Yeah, but it eats the final `\n`, that's why I used `:join`. I probably should have mentioned that. :-)

Comment: Nice catch. learning about `*` is also great.

Comment: How about `'<,'>s/.*/['&']/ | *s/]\_.\[/, /` then?

Comment: Yeah, that's better. Though I'd probably write the second part as `*s/]\n\[/, /e`.